# reSolve framwork: How to authenticate a user via HTTP-request (routeRegisterCallback)?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, resolvejs

I am new to web-app development and the reSolve framework I am using for the backend (javascript). Since the application will have multiple users with different authorizations, I am using the Authentication and Authorization module like described in the [documentation](https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/authentication-and-authorization) plus some lines from the [shopping-list-advanced example](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/examples/shopping-list-advanced/web/common/auth/route-register-callback.js).

The problem I am facing now is, **how to make the HTTP-request in order to actually authenticate a user** (register/login and also, logout)?

Since I couldn't find anything in the documentation, I've been trying a POST-request to `http://localhost:3000/register` but it always just returned `Access error: POST is not addressable by current executor`. What am I missing?

Another problem, or rather unclarity: In the example shopping-list-advanced what is "ROOT_JWT_TOKEN" and what is it used for?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself - at least the general path for the HTTP-request (see marked comment in picture):

[image]

Picture was taken from: https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/tree/master/packages/modules/resolve-module-auth